# Adding 1px to font size of every element inside a certain element

Tags: css, sass, font-size

Is there a way to add 1px to the current font-size of every element inside .wrap, without doing it manualy?

```
 .wrap{
      margin-top: 169px;
      .element1{
       font-size:30px;
      }
      .element2{
       font-size:20px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use SASS to make a mixin?

Comment: You could possibly do this with javascript/jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with normal CSS unless you use relative values (like `em`) and then set the font-size on `body`. What this does is create a standard font-size (whatever size you set on `body`) and then multiply it by whatever you set as the `em` value in your nested CSS. For example, if you set `body` to `font-size: 16px;` and then set everything else to `1em` (same as 16px) or `2em` (32px), etc., you can control this base size simply by changing the `font-size` on `body`.

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;  // 16 * 2 = 32px
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;  // 16 * 1.5 = 24px;
}
```

Also, since it appears you're using SASS, you can create variables for font-size and then change those variables.

```
$font-size-sm: 16px;
$font-size-lg: 32px;

h1 {
  font-size: $font-size-lg;
}

p {
  font-size: $font-size-sm;
}
```

You can also do math with these variables (as noted by Matt Fryer), so you could technically add the font-size to a variable if you don't care about keeping the same scale ratios between different font-sizes. (What I mean is that 16px / 32px is a different ratio from (16px + 1px) / (32px + 1px). If you scaled these changes up higher, you'd notice that the relative sizes were wonky.)

I work on a project where, depending on the environment, we add 1px to all font-sizes. The way we do this is we define all of the font-sizes in our design language in SASS variables on the sheet we use to import all of our .scss files for the build module. We have two of these sheets: one for each environment. The sheet for the environment with "font-sizes +1" simply has all of the font-size variables set to the "+1" values.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a SASS variable, like this:

```
$var: 1px;

.wrap
{
    margin-top: 169px;
    .element1
    {
        font-size: 30px + $var;
    }
    .element2
    {
        font-size: 20px + $var;
    }
}
```